# How to evaluate with user made condition in typescript

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements

i have a question regarding evaluating a user made condition in typescript.
In my case: I have an UI and a code behind (my model). 
My example data object looks like:

```
let data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        type: vw
        eos,
        costs: 23000
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        type: ford
        van,
        costs: 14000
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        type: nissan
        sumara,
        costs: 15000
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        type: honda
        civic,
        costs: 17500
    }
]
```

Well, in the UI the user got an input text field where he should make an request to give im all cars which are red, for example. The user input would look like this:
"costs <=15000", now this string should be used as a condition, so that i get back as result following ids: 1,2.

Anyone an idea how i can use the requeststring from a user in as a condition, like?:

```
data.forEach(object => {
   if(usercondition) //an idea how to solve this?
   {
      this.result.push(object);
   }});
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Why foreach? Why not [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic code looks something like this. But a word of caution: Use filters rather than taking inputs from the user as you can't possibly restrict what user can enter in a textbox. I am not sure how will you achieve this for the complex conditions.

The `usercondition` will hold the condition let's say `cost < 15000`. This value will be set by a text input.

```
addItem(usercondition: any) {

 this.data.forEach(obj =>
 {
     var strcondition = 'obj.' + usercondition;
     // console.log(strcondition) will print obj.cost < 15000

     if (eval(strcondition)) // evaluate the expression and check the condition
     {
       this.result.push(object);
     }
  });
 }
```